# Newbie Emberfire Querying

Tags: ember.js, firebase, emberfire

I am having trouble with simple EmberFire queries. 
I want to find a department object by name, and then add it to a college departments according to the data model described below.

The error I am receiving is:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'pushObject' of undefined

What am I doing wrong?

```
              store.query('college', {orderBy: 'name', equalTo: "CAS"}).then(function(c){
              var college = c
              console.log(college);
              dept.set('college',college);
              college.get('departments').pushObject(dept);
              dept.save();
              college.save()

            }
          )
```

Where department is:

```
  store.query('department', {orderBy: 'name', equalTo: "Testing One"}).then(function(depts){
              // var dept = depts.get('content')[0]
              var dept = depts})
```

Here is my full query:

```
    findOne(){
      var store = this.store
      // store.query('department', {orderBy: 'name', equalTo: "Testing One"}).then(function(depts){
      store.query('department', {orderBy: 'name', equalTo: "Testing One"}).then(function(depts){
          // var dept = depts.get('content')[0]
          var dept = depts
          console.log(dept);
          //Add it to college
          store.query('college', {orderBy: 'name', equalTo: "CAS"}).then(function(c){
              var college = c//.get('content')[0]
              console.log(college);
              dept.set('college',college);
              college.get('departments').pushObject(dept);
              dept.save();
              college.save()

            }
          )
      })
},
```

Department:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
   name: DS.attr('string'),
   faculty:DS.hasMany('faculty'),
   college: DS.belongsTo('college')
});
```

College:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  departments: DS.hasMany('department')
});
```

EDIT: c object from query:

```
Class
__ember1484688357664
:
"ember632"
__ember_meta__
:
Meta
__firebaseCleanup
:
()
_super
:
ROOT()
_updatingPromise
:
null
content
:
(...)
get content
:
GETTER_FUNCTION()
set content
:
SETTER_FUNCTION(value)
isLoaded
:
true
isUpdating
:
false
links
:
EmptyObject
manager
:
Class
meta
:
EmptyObject
query
:
Object
store
:
Class
type
:
quality-online@model:college:
__proto__
:
Class
```

Comment: Are you sure "c" is returning an object from the query? You should check that first. console.log(c) then check to see if it prints to the console. I may be missing the departments.

Comment: @talves please check updated answer. I printed the 'c'. It's a 'college' type. I assume it should have an empty array of departments if none are associated with it?

Comment: Sorry, you might want to try console.log(college.get('departments')), it should be undefined. Maybe you meant college.get('department') singular.

Comment: Please have look at the college model. 
I have 'departments' there.

Comment: I have put my suggestion in an answer, let me know if that is what you are looking for. I am not sure what your `college` object looks like when it returns, so I am making assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try something similar to the following:

```js
store.query('department', {orderBy: 'name', equalTo: "Testing One"}).then(function(c) {
  return c.get('firstObject');
}).then(function(college) {
  departments = college.get('departments');
  departments.pushObject(dept);
  ...
});
```

Comment: Of course, you will need to check for the return of null.

Comment: It works. Thank you so much. Where can I learn more about querying data with emberfire?

Comment: I usually just use the docs or review open source projects, but there are tutorials out there also. I have seen some presentations on youtube also. Glad it worked for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

talves's answer will work in most cases, but it is a bit ugly. It is the commonly accepted way to solve this since `EmberFire` doesn't really offer anything better. This is, however, an add-on which will work for all of your querying needs. You can check it out [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-emberfire-find-query).